# bootstrap col-md-offset not working?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using react and trying to render following :

```
render(){
return(
  <div className="col-md-12">
    <h1 className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-6">To do App</h1>


    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.text}/>
      <button>Add {this.state.items.length+1}</button>
    </form>


    <Todolist items={this.state.items}/> 
  </div>
)
}
```

col-md-6 is working but col-md-offset-6 is not working ?? I'm using bootstrap 4.

Comment: and why the col-md-12 ?

Comment: to make sure 12 columns are in total

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`.col-*-offset-*` was removed in Bootstrap 4.  The new syntax is simply `.offset-*-*` so you should be using `.offset-md-6` in your above code.

You can learn more about offsetting Bootstrap's Grid columns on their 4.x documentation:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the format of offset to `offset-md-6` in place of `col-md-offset-6`.

The Bootstrap 3 was supporting the format `col--offset-*` but in Bootsrap 4 the format is like `offset--*`